# how to compose a request google cloud storage (for parallel upload) using java

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to upload a file (500 MB) to the google cloud storage. (java)
I created a List of Soource objects and I need to add ObjectPreconditions , ifGenerationMatch () to each of the object in that list. 
I don't  understand how to use it. 
the errors I got from google were not informative at all.

```
 StorageObject metadata = new StorageObject()
                .setContentType("text/plain");

List<SourceObjects> sourceObjects = new ArrayList<SourceObjects>();
for (int i = 0; i <= chunkNumber; i++) {
    sourceObjects.add( new SourceObjects().setName(objectName +     ".chunk" + i) );
}

ComposeRequest composeReq = new ComposeRequest()
                .setSourceObjects(sourceObjects)
                .setDestination(metadata);


 storage.objects().compose(bucketName, fileName,composeReq).execute();
```

and this is the error:

```
{
  "code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Not Found",
    "reason" : "notFound"
  } ],
  "message" : "Not Found"
```

Comment: Do the objects you're adding in the chunkNumber loop exist? They need to exist before the compose operation, else you'll get a 404 error.

Comment: How about the bucket? Does it exist, and is bucketName set to that name? If so could you follow up with more specific details about your request: the bucket and object names and date/time when you attempted it - and if possible, a dump of the API requests being sent by the Java lib you're using (leaving off authorization tokens)? You could send to gs-team@google.com to avoid posting details publicly. Thanks.